# energy storage and flux produced by an inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

The unit of magnetic flux is the Weber and is proportional to L x I or Henrys X Amps. Flux is also proportional to J/I or energy per Amp.

Energy stored in an inductor is given as 1/2 LxIxI. When I ask where is the energy stored in an inductor the answer is given that it is stored in the magnetic flux.

The energy stored in the flux is LxI but the energy stored in the inductor is 1/2 LxIxI. So my question is where is the rest of the energy stored?

Answer (score 2):

"The unit of magnetic flux is the Weber and is proportional to L x I or Henrys X Amps."

This is pretty much correct. The self inductance, *L* of a coil (or in general a circuit without an iron core) may be  defined from the equation $$n\Phi=LI$$
in which $n$ is the effective number of turns on the coil, and $\Phi$ is the flux, assumed to pass through all $n$ turns.

So the unit of magnetic flux is indeed the henry ampere (small letters not capitals) or H A (capital letters!)

As you say, the *energy* stored in the coil is usually written as$$U=\frac{1}{2} L I^2.$$
This can be written, using the top equation, as $$U=\frac{1}{2}n\Phi I.$$

You come close to this when you say that "Flux is also proportional to J/I or energy per Amp.", but the statement in quotes is a rather curious mixture of quantities and units, and of course it suppresses the factor of $\frac{1}{2}.$

It is indeed correct that the units of $\Phi$ may be written as J/A or $\text{J A}^{-1}.$ We can show, in fact, that the units are the same, that is$$\text{Wb = HA = JA}^{-1}.$$
The easiest way to show this requires knowledge of electromagnetic induction and the volt (V). This gives the relationships between units:$$\text{V = Wb s}^{-1} \text{     in which    V = J A}^{-1} \text{s}^{-1}.$$
There is no missing energy! I'd hazard a guess that one cause of confusion is that you're not distinguishing between equations involving quantities (usually italicised) and relationships between units (upright letters in the *Système Internationale* and capitals when abbreviated to a single letter).

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help. I have been through the equations many times, but I am having a conceptual problem. I have seen it said that the energy stored in an inductor is stored in the flux. The flux is equal to L x I. When the current is doubled the flux is doubled, but the stored energy is quadrupled. If the energy is stored in the flux why does it not increase by a factor of four when the current is doubled? Is it possible to show that the unit of flux is energy squared rather than energy per ampere?

Comment: "If the energy is stored in the flux why does it not increase by a factor of four when the current is doubled?" The stored energy $does$ increase by a factor of 4 when the current doubles. Where is the suggestion that it doesn't?

Comment: Are you confusing the energy stored in the flux with the flux itself? We can show that the stored energy per unit volume is given by$$\frac{U}{V}=\frac{1}{2 \mu_0}B^2$$ in which $B$ is the flux density.

Comment: Every text that i have studied gives a quick coverage of flux and then moves instantly to flux density. Flux density only applies at a specific area of the flux field and is useful in understanding and solving many engineering type problems. After many years of thinking that i understood magnetics, i came upon the conceptual problem that i have tried to explain.

Comment: Every text that i have studied gives a few equations about flux and then quickly moves on to flux density. Flux density is very handy for understanding and solving many engineering type problems, but flux density applies only to a specific area of the flux field. My question involves the total flux produced by a steady state current flowing through an inductor. The energy stored in the inductor is proportional to the current squared yet the total flux is proportional to the current. If the energy is stored in the flux(perhaps incorrect?) then how is this possible?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the energy in (say) a toroidally-wound inductor is, or ought to be, proportional to the flux linked with the inductor. It isn't. It is proportional to the square of the flux. The flux is proportional to the current (for a given air-cored inductor); the energy is proportional to the current squared. This is a fundamental property of flux, which is usually expressed in terms of flux $density$; the equation I gave in my last comment is generally seen as rather fundamental!

Comment: A similar thing applies to the $electric$ field in a capacitor. The energy stored is proportional to the square of the voltage between the plates. The energy is stored in the electric field in the gap between the plates. But the electric field strength, $E,$ is simply proportional to the voltage. The 'reason' is that the energy stored per unit volume in an electric field is given by$$\frac{U}{V}=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2.$$ A similar relationship applies for a squashed or stretched solid: the energy stored is proportional to square of the applied force!

Comment: I am sure that what you have said is true. I do believe that the energy stored is proportional to the flux squared. I guess that what i am looking for is an equation to show this - that uses flux (phi) and not flux density (B), since B only applies at a particular area of a closed surface around the inductor. I am new to this site. I just got a note saying this discussion should be moved to "chat" . I don't know how to do that, so good by, and thanks for your attempt to help me. I will look to see if you post an answer.

Comment: Don't give up! (a) If you substitute for $I$ from the first equation in my answer into the second we get$$U=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n^2\Phi^2}{L}.$$ Is that what you're looking for? (b) "since B only applies at a particular area of a closed surface around the inductor." Don't know what you mean here: in the simple case of a toroidal coil, $B$ is approximately the same everywhere inside the coil.

Comment: It is funny, but i finally derived that equation since my last comment. However; a new mystery has shown up. The above equation suggests that the energy is stored in the flux, but the L x I x I equation suggests that the energy is in the current (moving charge). It seems that neither assumption is correct. For a fixed amount of energy in an inductor the larger the L, the smaller the current and the larger the flux and vice versa. A rectangular pulse of voltage (volt sec) causes a ramp of current. It is the product of the volts and current that is the energy that charges the inductor.

Comment: The value of the inductor determines how much of the charging energy goes into flux(volt sec) and how much goes into moving charge(current). Please let me know if you disagree with this.

Comment: I have solved my conceptual problem. There is no energy in the flux or the current. Energy is the cross product of the flux and the current. If we apply one volt for one second to a one Henry inductor, the current will ramp up to one Ampere. The energy put into the inductor is the product of the voltage and current during that one second and is equal to 1/2 watt sec, or 1/2 Joule. The unit of flux is the volt second, so our applied volt second created one weber of flux. When the inductor is discharged the collapsing flux produces the necessary counter voltage to bring the current back to zero.

Comment: I'm glad you're no longer troubled. your statement that "There is no energy in the flux [...]" contradicts just about  all the electromagnetism textbooks written since the time of Maxwell, but I suspect that you don't mean your claim to be taken literally.

Comment: Well here is my logic: Apply one volt second to one henry, the stored energy is 1/2 joule and the flux is one weber. Now apply one volt second to 2 henry and the stored energy is 1/4 joule and the flux is one weber. As the size of the inductance approaches infinity the stored energy approaches zero and the flux is still one weber. I hope my math is correct. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: (a) Your 'flux of 1 Wb' is in fact a flux $linkage,$ that is $n\Phi,$ $n$ being the number of turns on your inductor, and $\Phi$ being the flux. (b) We can show that for a toroidally-wound coil, $L=\frac{\mu_0 A n^2}{\ell}$, so $L$ prop'l to $n^2$ if we keep the cross-sectional area, $A,$ and the axial length, $\ell,$ the same. So we can double $L$ by increasing $n$ by a factor of $\sqrt 2.$ In that case, in the situations you describe, $n\Phi$ stays the same, so $\Phi$ decreases from 1 Wb to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ Wb. The stored energy decreases from 1/2 J to 1/4 J, so energy prop'l $\Phi^2$ !

Comment: We also have an equation that says energy prop'l to current squared. In my mind these are just 2 ways of calculating the stored energy. we can't assume the energy is stored in the flux or the current just from the equations used to calculate the stored energy. The inductor that i use for mind experiments is a single turn of an infinitely thin perfect conductor in free space. Collapsing flux does not deliver energy, it delivers volt seconds. The same volt seconds that we used to put current into the inductor. The same volt seconds needed to bring the current back to zero and return the energy.

Comment: "we can't assume the energy is stored in the flux or the current just from the equations used to calculate the stored energy." No indeed. The notion that magnetic flux has energy (of amount $\frac{1}{2} \mu_0 B^2$ per unit volume) doesn't just get its support from the energy stored in an inductor. For example, electromagnetic waves can carry energy through a vacuum. How else but in the electric and magnetic fields of which they consist?

Comment: As we charge an inductor we put in energy as the product of volt seconds and current. When we discharge the inductor(thru a resistor) we get back the volt seconds from the collapsing flux times the decaying current. So in my mind, the voltage part of the watt seconds is stored in the flux and the current part of the watt seconds is stored in the circulating current. The ratio of the flux stored to the current stored is the inductance. Due to # of character limitations i must use multiple comments to express one thought.

Comment: Wow! you got an answer in between my 2 comments. I think we are in agreement. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for making me think (especially getting my head round your numerical 'paradox' about flux (linkage) and energy.